# Is there a way to trigger auto update of linked Google Sheet cells in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Slide doc that has linked Google Sheets cells in it.  This is not a linked chart.  There is plenty of documentation out there on how to auto-refresh charts as the code below:

```
function createTrigger() {

  // Trigger every 5 minute
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateSheets')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
}

/*
* Update all charts in the presentation
* Use trigger (minutes or hours)
*/
function updateSheets(){
  var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
    var slide = gotSlides[i];
    var sheetsCharts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
    for (var k = 0; k < sheetsCharts.length; k++) {
      var shChart = sheetsCharts[k];
      shChart.refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine if you are able to put cells of the sheet into a "table chart" for importing to Slides, but I would like to keep the formatting I have set up in the sheet itself and not have the added step of the table chart. The table shown in blue "Lathes" is what I have been trying to get to auto-refresh on time or on edit.  What I would like to be able to do is copy and paste the cells directly into my presentation so that the formatting remains what I have specified and not what the "table chart" built in formatting is. The update all button in the linked items tab of the Google Slides app will update the linked cells but I have yet to find a Google App Script command to do the same.
[Chart shown highlighted that mimics data in A4-C10.  I am able to auto update this chart if put into a slides doc with the given code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jojdc.png)

I would basically like to be able to have a script run the same function that is triggered when the "update all" button is pressed in the linked items tab.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by "This works fine if you are able to put cells of the sheet into a "table chart" for importing to Slides, but I would like to keep the formatting I have set up in the sheet itself and not have the added step of the table chart."? Maybe give a sample or a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited, hopefully this makes things more clear.  Basically you can have a chart (usually a graph of some kind like pie charts or bar graph) mimic cells in your sheet by using the "table chart" option.  these can be easily updated in slides using a script as the one I have posted but you cannot change the formatting of the chart.

Comment: I understand your issue now. What you want is not to refresh a table chart, but a linked table?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unfortunately so far it is not possible to refresh linked tables with the API

It certainly would be a useful feature, indeed there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/126790287) for it on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

I recommend you to "star" it to increase visibility and stay updated about its implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve started and commented on the feature request! You’ve been a big help.